# TS SS Vector similarity using matrices

Tags: python, nlp, vectorization, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have two sets of vectors A,B and I want to compute the TS-SS similarity for each vector in A compared to every vector in B.

I have an implementation (from https://github.com/taki0112/Vector_Similarity) used for 2 vectors, however when I tried using it for matrices (function "compute_matrix_sim") - it is very inefficient and takes forever.

Is there a more vectorized approach to use TS-SS for matrices?

Thanks!

```
import math
import numpy as np


class TS_SS:
    def Cosine(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        return np.dot(vec1, vec2.T) / (np.linalg.norm(vec1) * np.linalg.norm(vec2))

    def VectorSize(self, vec: np.ndarray):
        return np.linalg.norm(vec)

    def Euclidean(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        return np.linalg.norm(vec1 - vec2)

    def Theta(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        return np.arccos(self.Cosine(vec1, vec2)) + np.radians(10)

    def Triangle(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        theta = np.radians(self.Theta(vec1, vec2))
        return (self.VectorSize(vec1) * self.VectorSize(vec2) * np.sin(theta)) / 2

    def Magnitude_Difference(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        return abs(self.VectorSize(vec1) - self.VectorSize(vec2))

    def Sector(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        ED = self.Euclidean(vec1, vec2)
        MD = self.Magnitude_Difference(vec1, vec2)
        theta = self.Theta(vec1, vec2)
        return math.pi * (ED + MD) ** 2 * theta / 360

    def __call__(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        return self.Triangle(vec1, vec2) * self.Sector(vec1, vec2)


def compute_matrix_sim(m1, m2):
    similarity = TS_SS()
    ans = np.zeros((len(m1), len(m2)))
    for i, vec_m1 in enumerate(m1):
        for j, vec_m2 in enumerate(m2):
            ans[i, j] = similarity(vec_m1, vec_m2)
    return ans


# Usage
v1 = np.random.random_sample((40, 80))
v2 = np.random.random_sample((2000000, 80))
x = compute_matrix_sim(v1, v2)
print(x)
```

Comment: What you are doing right now is, to wait to finish one calculation, then start the next. So no matter how powerful your machine is. Try multiprocessing. It helps to  split your similarity measures to parallel processes. It helps to use multiple CPU cores and run multiple similarity measures at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import torch


class TS_SS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thetaval = 0
        self.vecnorm1 = 0
        self.vecnorm2 = 0

    def Theta(self, vec1, vec2):
        return (torch.arccos(torch.mm(vec1,vec2.T)/(self.vecnorm1*self.vecnorm2.T))
                + np.radians(10))

    def Triangle(self, vec1, vec2):
        self.thetaval = self.Theta(vec1, vec2)
        return ((self.vecnorm1 * self.vecnorm2.T * torch.sin(self.thetaval))
                / 2)



    def Sector(self, vec1: np.ndarray, vec2: np.ndarray):
        ED = torch.cdist(vec1,vec2,p=2)
        MD = torch.abs(self.vecnorm1 - self.vecnorm2.T)
        # theta = self.Theta(vec1, vec2)
        return (1/2) * ((ED + MD) ** 2) * self.thetaval

    def __call__(self, vec1, vec2):
        self.thetaval = 0
        self.vecnorm1 = vec1.norm(p=2, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        self.vecnorm2 = vec2.norm(p=2, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        return self.Triangle(vec1, vec2) * self.Sector(vec1, vec2)


v1 = torch.tensor([[3.0,4.0]])
v2 = torch.tensor([[4.0,3.0]])
similarity = TS_SS()
print(similarity(v1, v2))
```

Comment: I guess this will help you and it will be easy to do all of these calculations on GPU by just pushing tensors on that moreover you don't have to use a loop.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @FarooqWani, Can can we get this to work when both vectors are identical?

Comment: Yeah, it  works with identical vectors also

Comment: @FarooqWani, My bad. I messed up a little bit! Thank you. Is there any way I can use this, to find similarity between two large vector, and present as a smaller vector? V1=[e1, e2..... en], V2 = [e1, e2,...en], output O = [e1, e2, ... em], m<n. Thank you for your help.